# Visa card number is not accepted in IRCTC website

Tags: india, bookings, payment, irctc

What to do when VISA credit/debit cards are not recognized by IRCTC site to make reservations. I don't have access to Indian cards.

Comment: Have you contacted them or searched online help?

Comment: I guess you can book IRCTC Train tickets from travel portals like MakeMyTrip or Yatra. There it might accept your VISA card.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extensive account of how to buy Indian rail tickets on the website of the man in seat 61.

https://www.seat61.com/India.htm#Buy-tickets-online

It is far too long and complex to sumarise here but basically you either use an independent agency which charges a small fee or you register on the official railway site. He also provides a whole list of things which can go wrong with suggested remediation actions.